# Matching contents of 2 arrays angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, kineticjs

I have 2 arrays of the following contents:

```
var answer = [[2,1],[1,1],[0,0]];
var selectedObject = [[1,1],[0,0],[2,1]];
```

I want to match the contents of both the arrays. `_.Equals` is not working for me in the above condition. As the contents being same are not in same position in array.

Is there any easy way to match the contents of above mentioned arrays.

Any demo code, example, or logic will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it. Using `_.Equals` and basic for loop. It was so simple.

```
if(answerArray.length != selectedAnsArray.length)
{
    //wrong answer
    return;
}
else
{
    for(var x = 0; x < answerArray.length; x++)
    {
        for(var y = 0; y < selectedAnsArray.length; y++)
        {
            if(_.isEqual(answerArray[x],selectedAnsArray[y]))
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count==answerArray.length)
    {
       //correct answer
       return;
    }
    else
    {
      //wrong answer
      return;
    }
}
```

Comment: you might want to either break out of the `count++` for loop, or check if `count >= answerArray.length` - otherwise if you have `equal` elements within the array, you would produce a count higher than `answerArray.length`(e.g. `[[0,0],[0,0]]`)

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
var baz = [];

angular.forEach(answer, function(key) {
  if (-1 === selectedObject.indexOf(key)) {
    baz.push(key);
           }
        });    
   if(baz.length==0)
       {
        //Not matched
       }
   else
       {
         //matched
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about angularjs. But basic logic goes like this,

```
j=0
for(i=0; i<arr_len; i++){

   if(arr1[i] == arr2[i]{
   j++;
   }

}

if(arr_len == j){
    arrays are equal.

}
```